# Ignore known header of video file

Tags: vlc

i have video uncompressed .avi video files. however they come with a known 2048kb header at the beginning of the file, such that no video program (Vlc player) recognises the file as video files. can i force VLC to ignore the first 2048kb? how?

what would be the easiest way to remove this header?

Comment: you can use the `tail` [command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no known to me way of getting vlc to use a larger "probesize" or somehow just skip to byte X.

Also unfortunately there is no known to me way to add some "camouflage" or even add an empty chunk to the front of an avi container. Next approach could be to genereate a reference movie but also no automatic usage tools available at the best of my knowledge. And as there is also no way to just "set or change" the start offset of a file, we have to copy it.

My recommendation for copying parts of files is this sourceforge project: skf

- https://sourceforge.net/projects/swissfileknife/?source=typ_redirect
- [some examples](http://stahlworks.com/dev/?tool=partcopy)